# Trouble installing package ‘export’ after upgrading R version. Is there an alternative to this package?

Tags: r

I keep seeing this error: package ‘export’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3).

I tried various ways, such as:

`install.packages("export")`

`devtools::install_github("tomwenseleers/export")`

I successfully used this package in the past and would very much like to use it again!

AN UPDATE:
Solution provided in the comments here: [Issues with RStudio version to 3.6.3: troubles installing packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73666197/issues-with-rstudio-version-to-3-6-3-troubles-installing-packages?noredirect=1#comment130086686_73666197)

Comment: The [package was removed from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=export) back in 2020 because they authors did no make requested changes to work with newer versions of R. See the existing duplicate on how to install packages from the archive.

Comment: I have read about the issues with CRAN and I believe I tried getting it from GitHub... It worked in the past even through it was not easy. But this time I cannot make it work unfortunately...

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error when you install from github? If you get a specific error message, be sure to include that. Otherwise there aren't really any details here to offer alternative suggestions for.

Comment: I have notes on what worked in the past (about 9 months ago): ```install.packages('devtools')
require(devtools)
devtools::install_github("tomwenseleers/export")
install.packages('export')```
It seems that 'devtools' package is being installed, but then an error message states that there is no package called ‘devtools’. I tried multiple times...

Comment: Most likely something went wrong installing devtools. Carefully check the logs for error message. But devtools is likely overkill for this. You can probably just try `remotes::install_github("tomwenseleers/export")`. The `remotes` package has fewer dependencies.

Comment: Thank you... I have just tried what you suggested and I see some errors. For example: ERROR: dependency 'flextable' is not available for package 'export'
* removing 'C:/Users/ikrist/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/export'. I also tried ```BiocManager::install("tomwenseleers/export")``` but everything results in "there is no package called ‘export’".

Comment: If flextable is a dependency, try installing that first with `install.packages("flextable")`. You'll probably want to install all the dependencies listed on the main README: https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export under "Get the latest development version:", just swap `remotes` for `devtools`. Since it doesn't appear to be a bioconductor package, I'm not surprised that `BiocManager::install` doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help. It seems that two packages on the list are causing the issue (maybe these also are not on CRAN; it seems that they are being installed, but then do not exist): > require("flextable")
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘flextable’
> require("rgl")  Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘crosstalk’

Comment: I was able to get ‘crosstalk’, but then unable to install 'shiny' and 'bslib'. Same issue as with 'flextable'. Something like: ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'htmltools' 0.5.1.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.2 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'bslib'

Comment: There are many issues with version 3.6.3; it was never such a struggle before. Many packages cannot be installed. For example:   * installing *source* package 'dbplyr' ...
** package 'dbplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.11 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace Execution halted ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'dbplyr'