# Issues with RStudio version 3.6.3: troubles installing packages

Tags: r, install.packages, rtools

I upgraded RStudio version to 3.6.3 and have endless issues installing the packages. I have never experienced that before and I am not an expert, so it has been a huge struggle. I posted a question on StackOverflow ([Trouble installing package ‘export’ after upgrading R version. Is there an alternative to this package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653522/trouble-installing-package-export-after-upgrading-r-version-is-there-an-alter?noredirect=1#comment130065197_73653522)) with several updates in the comments... The issues are always similar: it seems that the package is being loaded, but then it is not available.

For example:

```
** package 'dbplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.11 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'dbplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/...../Documents/R/win-library/3.6/dbplyr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status


    > install.packages('Rtools ')
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/..../Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools ’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
```

Comment: RTools is not a package ... you can install it from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ . But it is probably easier of you use package binaries.

Comment: ... hmm reading the messages suggests to try to install rlang with version >= 1.0.0

Comment: upgrading R (not RStudio, version 3.6.3 looks very much like an R version number and not an RStudio version: RStudio versions look like v1.4.1106-5 or v2022.07.0+548.pro5) to 3.6.3 is a bit odd, as it's still a very old version.  Is there a reason you can't upgrade to a *current* (or at least more recent) version of R (e.g., at least > 4.0, current version is 4.2.1)?  That will make things **much** easier ...

Comment: I have not used RStudio for a few months and when I opened it it suggested an update. So I said OK. I will try to figure out how to upgrade R. Here is what I see in RStudio Console: > version
    ....                     
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

Comment: To download R see https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/ . Just click through the installer. Rstudio should find the most recent R version

Comment: Thank you so very much! I installed a new R version, so RStudio was upgraded and everything works!